# Laravel data dependent on selected dropdown

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

Been trying to dynamically change the value of an input field depending on the product selected from a dropdown menu for an hour now and I can't seem to figure out how.
This is how I populate the products:

```
<select name="product_id" v-model="form.product_id" id="product_id" class="form-control" :class="{'is-invalid': form.errors.has('product_id') }">
       <option v-for="product in products" :value="product.product_id">{{product.product_name}}</option>
</select>
```

and this is how i'm intending to put its product quantity depending on the product selected from the dropdown.

```
       <td><input name="product_qty" value="" class="form-control" disabled></input></td>
```

I'm thinking of creating a method called getQty() and then calling it in the input tag like this @change="getQty", however i can't seem to figure it out as i'm still a beginner on vue.js

Edit:
Here export data:

```
export default {

    data () {

        return {

            orders: {},
            suppliers: {},
            products: {},
            form: new Form({
                recipient: '',
                supplier_id: '',
                order_type: '',
                to_address: '',
                s_address: '',
                status: '',
                product_name: ''
            }),
            selected: this.products.length ? this.products[0] : null
        }
    },
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, hope it will meet your requirement

in your template's select option

```
   <select @click="selectProduct(product)"  class="custom-select" v-model="form.product_id">
        <option disabled value="">Select Product</option>
        <option v-for="product in products" :key="product.product_id" :value="product.product_id">{{product.product_name}} </option>
   </select>
```

in export default:

```
 data() {
        return {
            selected: this.products ? this.products[0] : null
        };
    },
    methods: {
       selectProduct(product) {
            this.selected = product;
            this.$emit('selected', product);
            }
    },
```

On your template: Assuming your quantity in product.product_qty. change this as per your required

```
  <td><input :class="{ 'selected': product == selected }" name="product_qty" value="" class="form-control" disabled>{{ product.product_qty }}</input></td>
```

Comment: it returns an error of "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: doesnt return any error however, when i select a value on my the <input> remains blank and doesnt show any value.

Comment: did u change {{ product.product_qty }} ? 

what is the name of quantity column in your product table?

Comment: I have posted another question regarding this problem of mine, please feel free to check it, since I've used another method which is much more efficient for me. Thanks. And yes I did change product.product_qty to the correct product table.

Comment: please share the link of that issue

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58916222/laravel-vue-js-binding-select-data-to-another-element