# Laravel VUE JS binding select data to another element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to show the product quantity of a product depending on the product that was selected in the dropdown menu, however I can't figure out how to specifically get quantity from the lists.

Here is the select menu:

```
<select class="form-control" v-model="form.product_list">
  <option disabled value="">Select Product</option>
  <option v-for="product in products" :key="product.product_id" :value="product.product_id">{{product.product_name}}</option>
</select>
```

When you select a product from the select menu it binds it to `form.product_list`, after that I'm trying to show the product quantity instead of the `product_id` here: This does work however it shows the `product_id` instead of product quantity.

```
<td class="text-xs-left">
  <p>{{form.product_list}}</p>
</td>`
```

Here's the data:

```
data () {
  return {
    products: {},
    form: new Form({
      product_list: '',
    })
  }
}
```

I'm aware that changing `:value="product.product_id"` to `:value="product.product_quantity"` inside the select element will solve the issue, however I'm still going to need the `product_id` when I insert it into the database later on.

Answer (score 1):

Change its value from product.product_id to product.product_qty. It will work hopefully

```
<option v-for="product in products" :key="product.product_id" :value="product.product_qty">{{product.product_name}}</option>
```

Comment: I cannot do that as im gonna need the product.product_id when im gonna insert it in the database later on.

Comment: then make an onClick event, whenever someone click the product that onClick event will fire a method which assign product_qty value to a data variable. and return that data variable  (containing qty ) to your view template.